# Time of the final Apollo 11 television broadcast and splashdown

Tags: apollo-program

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_11), the Apollo 11 splashdown occurred at July 24, 1969, 16:50:35 UTC.

1. Does anyone have a referenced source confirming the July 24, 16:50:35 UTC splashdown time?
2. Does anyone have a source for what time [the July 23 television broadcast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_11#Return) -- the final broadcast of the mission -- took place?

I'm looking for reference(s) I can cite.

Answer (score 3):

A search for `apollo 11 timeline site:history.nasa.gov` yields [a handy reference for both times](https://history.nasa.gov/SP-4029/Apollo_11i_Timeline.htm). The final TV broadcast was 22:45 to 23:04 UTC on the 23rd.

The timeline is part of the larger ["Apollo By The Numbers" statistical reference](https://history.nasa.gov/SP-4029/SP-4029.htm), which is a great place to find lots of trivial data about the missions.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the [Apollo 11 Lunar Surface Journal](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/office/pao/History/alsj/a11/a11.html)

There are some slightly different times for splash down:

> 195:18:18 Swim 1: Splashdown! Apollo has splashdown. According to the
> Apollo 11 Mission Report, the moment of splashdown is given as
> 195:18:35. However, PAO will give an unofficial time of 195:18:21 GET.

[Source](https://history.nasa.gov/afj/ap11fj/27day9-entry.html#1951821)

(Public Affairs Officer (PAO) Jack King) ( 195:18:35 means 195 hours, 18 minutes and 35 seconds after liftoff)

> Figure  13-1  depicts  the  U.S.S. Hornet  and associated aircraft
> positions  at  the  time of  command module landing at 195:18:35
> (16:50  G.m.t. ).   The  command module landed at a point  calculated
> by  recovery  forces to  be latitude  13°19 '  N and  longitude 169°9
> '   W

[Source](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/office/pao/History/alsj/a11/a11MIssionReport_1971015566.pdf)

> The spacecraft re-entered the atmosphere at 400,000 feet at 12:35 P.M.
> EOT, and 13 minutes later splashed into the Pacific Ocean
> approximately 825 nm southwest of Hawaii.

[Source](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/office/pao/History/alsj/a11/A11_PAOMissionReport.html)

*Adding 13 minutes to 12:35 P.M. EOT is 12:48 EOT or 16:48 UTC.*

> Figure 13-1 depicts  the  Hornet and  associated aircraft positions
> at the  time of  caamand module landing  at 195:18:35  (1650 G.m.t.).
> The  com­mand module landed at  a  point  calculated by  recovery
> forces to be 13 de­grees 19 minutes north latitude and 169 degrees 9
> minutes west  longitude .

> The entry phase  was normal,  and the  command module landed   in  the
> Pacific Ocean at  195-l/4 hours .

195-l/4 hours or 195:15 would be 16:15 UTC

> After an automatic  entry sequence and landing system deploy­ment, the
> command module landed in the Pacific Ocean at 195-l/2 hours.

[Source](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/office/pao/History/alsj/a11/a11mr_NoMissingPages_19700008096.pdf)

Three different times within the same Apollo 11 Mission Report.

> In this report,  all  actual times  are given  as  elapsed  time
> from range  zero  (g.e.t.), which  is established as the  integral
> second before  lift-off. Range zero for this mission was 13:32:00
> G.m.t.,  July 16, 1969.

*Adding 195:18:18 mission time to 13:32:00 lift-off time is 16:50:18 UTC, but we got also 16:50:21 and 16:50:35.*